# How to get local country time by TimeZone Id in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

i have hosted my site in canada server.  my clients are in different countries. when they add device i have stored timezone id. for example.

```
'Pacific Standard Time'
'Mountain Standard Time (Mexico)'
'India Standard Time'
```

now in sql server how can i get country time from timezone Id which is stored in my database like above.?

Answer (score 2):

`sys.time_zone_info` has UTC offsets. This will give you a complete list

```
SELECT * FROM sys.time_zone_info
```

From here, you can simply join on the value stored in your table.

MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt612790.aspx

Comment: `sys.time_zone_info` is introduced with SQL Server 2016. For some reason the documentation says starting with 2008 and 2016 on different lines.

Comment: @Mike That'll teach me to trust the doco - my local server is 2016 :)

Answer (score 1):

Reading the SQL Server from Time Zone can be one way to achieve the current time zone of where the SQL Server is installed.

```
DECLARE @TimeZone VARCHAR(50)
EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation',
'TimeZoneKeyName',@TimeZone OUT
SELECT @TimeZone
```

Comment: Is there a way of getting the current time zone name WITHOUT using xp_regread? Didn't SQL Server 2016 add enough time zone functionality to not have to rely on this 'hack'?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL SERVER 2008 or above you can try this...

```
SELECT [DateTimeUtil].[UDF_ConvertLocalToLocalByTimezoneIdentifier] (
    'GMT Standard Time', -- the original timezone in which your datetime is stored
    'Middle East Standard Time', -- the target timezone for your user
    '2014-03-30 01:55:00' -- the original datetime you want to convert
)
```

Source: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39421/how-to-handle-timezone-properly-in-sql-server#comment118319_64418

For more clarification go through the above link...

Comment: hi Thanks but where to add udf [DateTimeUtil].[UDF_ConvertLocalToLocalByTimezoneIdentifier] ? i mean what i have to return from function and how?